How to limit width of a cell in an array?
I am using Iguanatex in PowerPoint.
I am making MCQs questions in PPT.
Here in PPT it is limited space, and I am using four coloumns and two rows to write 4 options. Like this below
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent $\begin{array}{cccc}

\textbf{(A)} &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}  & \hspace{1in} \vspace{0.3cm} \textbf{(B)} &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \\
\textbf{(C)} &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  & \hspace{1in} \textbf{(D)} & \text{No such matrix exists as matrix multiplication is not commutative.}

\end{array}$
\end{document}


Now in the last option(d) there is a text and when I am writing this text, it go outside the ppt, so I want to write it in two or three lines to cut the length short using "\"
like this
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent $\begin{array}{cccc}

\textbf{(A)} &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}  & \hspace{1in} \vspace{0.3cm} \textbf{(B)} &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \\
\textbf{(C)} &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  & \hspace{1in} \textbf{(D)} & \text{No such matrix exists as \\ matrix multiplication is not commutative.}

\end{array}$
\end{document}

Or
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \noindent $\begin{array}{cccc}
        
        \textbf{(A)} &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}  & \hspace{1in} \vspace{0.3cm} \textbf{(B)} &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \\
        \textbf{(C)} &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  & \hspace{1in} \textbf{(D)} & \text{No such matrix exists as \newline matrix multiplication is not commutative.}
        
    \end{array}$
\end{document}

But then the code is not running...
What should I do??
Thanks in advance....

You should insert text in the last cell in \parbox:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent$\begin{array}{cccc}
(\mathbf{A})    
    & \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}   
        & (\textbf{B})
            &  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \\[3ex]
(\mathbf{C})
    & \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  
        & (\mathbf{D})
            & \parbox{11em}{No such matrix exists as \newline matrix multiplication is not commutative.}
    \end{array}$
\end{document}


BTW, in math environment you should use \mathbf for denote matrix instead of \textbf. Also parenthesis should not be boldfaced

+1. I would get rid of \newline, though.

I would like to suggest that you (a) use a \parbox directive to encase the text for case (D) and (b) use the capabilities of LaTeX to automate the formatting of the contents of columns 1 and 3. The less visual formatting one needs to perform, the better in general. I would also left-align the column contents in order to give the material a more list-like look and feel.
I chose a width of 5.5cm for the \parbox as it lets the material be typeset in 2 rows -- mimicking the appearance of the material in the adjacent cells. If you're ok with spreading the material across 3 rows, I suggest you use a width of ca 4cm. The command \raggedright suppresses full justification.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'bmatrix' environment
\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{($\bfseries}l<{$)}} % automatic text mode, bold
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{@{} L l @{\hspace{1cm}} L l @{}}
A & \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix} &  
B & \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\[3ex]
C & \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} &
D & \parbox{5.5cm}{\raggedright No such matrix exists as matrix multiplication is not commutative.}
\end{array}$
\end{document}


How about this solution?
The code works well in IguanaTeX in PowerPoint.
It is also not necessary to wrap the text manually.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \textbf{(A)} &  $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}$   & \textbf{(B)}  &  $\begin{bmatrix} 1   & 0 \\ 0        & 1 \end{bmatrix}$  \\[5mm]
        \textbf{(C)} &  $\begin{bmatrix} 1                  & 1 \\ 1        & 1 \end{bmatrix}$      & \textbf{(D)}  & \begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}No such matrix exists as matrix multiplication is not commutative.\end{minipage}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


